# Creating a virtual path in asp.net/Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, path, virtual

We are moving a web app to the MS Azure environment and had to change where photos are stored.  Azure uses a blob environment that we access via a mapped cloud drive.  We dynamically set the drive letter at app start.  All of this is working fine and the pictures save correctly.

We need to set a URL path to these pictures so that users can view them.  In the old app, that worked fine because they were stored within the app environment but now they are outside.  How can I set a mapping for something like http://myapp.com/photos/abc.jpg will point to h:\abc.jpg?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like all you need to do is create a virtual directory in IIS in the root of your application called `photos` that is mapped to `h:\`.

To do this, open IIS Manager, right-click on your site, and select *Add Virtual Directory...*. Set the alias to `photos` and the physical path to `h:\`.

Comment: I realized that this won't work.  The drive letter is dynamically created and there is no way (that I can find) to force a particular drive letter.  So on app_start it may select H but the next time it may choose J.  Is there a way within the app?

Comment: @JonLeach you can follow the process [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/04/16/using-smb-to-share-a-windows-azure-drive-among-multiple-role-instances.aspx) to map a drive to a particular drive letter.